# SQL construct or statement is not supported

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, if-statement

I been new to using SQL and I've been getting an error:

> sql construct or statement is not supported

In visual studio each time I execute this statement:

```
IF (SELECT [Product_Availability] FROM Product WHERE [Product_Name] = @name) = 'True' 
UPDATE [Product] SET [Product_Availability] = 'False' 
WHERE ([Product_Name] = @name) 
ELSE 
UPDATE Product SET [Product_Availability] = 'True' 
WHERE ([Product_Name] = @name)
```

Though it works despite the error in the query part of visual studio; however, it doesn't when I call it inside my database handler class. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simplify to a single statement instead of all these if/else things?

```
UPDATE dbo.Product_Availability 
  SET Product_Availability = CASE Product_Availability
    WHEN 'True' THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END
WHERE Product_Name = @name;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still pretty new to SQL so I'm sloppy with it.